# jquery.validate errors in specific spans

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I try  to control the jquery.validate errors.
I want to show them in a "span" i created for each one of them

not sure why, but my JS not working

this is my html code

```
  <li>
      <label for="name">name</label>
      <span  class="errmsg" for="name"></span> 
      <input type="text" name="name"   />
    </li>
  <li>
      <label for="age">age</label>
      <span  class="errmsg" for="age"></span> 
      <input type="text" name="age"   />
    </li>
```

this is my JS code

```
...
success: function(label) {
       label.html("&nbsp;").addClass("checked");
    },

        wrapper: "div",  // a wrapper around the error message 

        errorPlacement: function(error, element) { 
                element.parent().next('.errmsg').html(error); 
       } 
});
```

Comment: Have you tried to use firebug to see where this is failing?

Comment: yes. it didn't create any new span. and not inserting the error to the correct span

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<span>` is not in the right place for your traversing (in relation to the `<input>`, it's immediately before the element, so instead of this:

```
element.parent().next('.errmsg')
```

Which looks for the next `<li>` with a class of `errmsg`, you need this:

```
element.closest('li').find('.errmsg')
//or just:
element.prev('.errmsg')
//or 20 other ways...
```

The [`.closest('li')`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) is the most flexible for changes later, the [`.prev('.errmsg')`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) is the fastest.

Comment: because some of the span are before the input and others after.
i try to use:
 element.parent().closest('span.errmsg').html(error);

but it didn't work any idea?

Comment: @user186585 - You should try the answers I posted :)  `element.closest('li').find('.errmsg')` will work if it's before or after, anywhere in the same `<li>`.  Or if it's always a sibling, just `element.siblings('.errmsg')` will work.